# Kea DHCP error: conflicting reservation for address 192.168.1.2 with existing lease Address - how to clear the lease?

Tags: ip, allocation, dhcp

I am running ISC Kea DHCP server with a reservation of `192.168.1.2` for a MAC `aa.bb.cc.dd.ee.ff`.

Client successfully obtained IP `192.168.1.2`, but after rebooting it is not getting the IP anymore and the Kea log file states `conflicting reservation for address 192.168.1.2 with existing lease Address: 192.168.1.2`, so it looks like it fails to recognize that the `DHCPREQUEST` is coming from the MAC for which the IP is reserved ***and to which the IP has already been issued***.

This looks to me like it may be a bug.

How do I 'clear' that lease from the leases list?

Comment: Could you provide your reservations block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no reservation for the client, Kea will allocate an address from anywhere in the pool. Kea does not check that the selected address is not reserved. To solve this, the pool ranges and the reserved addresses must not overlap. For example:

```
    {
        "subnet": "10.3.0.0/16",
        "pools": [ { "pool": "10.3.64.0 - 10.3.95.252" } ],
        "reservations": [
            { "hw-address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", "ip-address": "10.3.0.1" },
            { "hw-address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", "ip-address": "10.3.1.1" },
            { "hw-address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", "ip-address": "10.3.2.1" }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Your answer is confusing. Let's be unambiguous: a reserved IP address can be configured with or without a pool being configured and vice versa and the reservation(s) may or may not overlap the pool. Assuming an IP address is reserved for a specific HW MAC address, then when a DHCP REQ arrives from that MAC address Kea *should* give the IP reserved for it to that client. If there's no reservation, Kea should issue another unused and unreserved IP from the pool. What exactly do you mean by "Kea does not check that the selected address is not reserved"? Do you mean an IP address or a MAC address?